# Step into a class library in asp.net using visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, class-library, breakpoints

I'll start by saying that I have searched SO and not found an answer to my issue.

I want to place a breakpoint in my asp.net code behind, and when a method or function of a class library is being called, I would like to be able to step into the class library code.

I have added the class library code files to my asp.net solution file.

Attach to process does not work (the class library code behind does not come up). I have also confirmed that the pdb file exists in the \bin folder .... according to this post [ASP.NET Class Library not hitting break points](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8792122/165694)

This is my screenshot of processes:
[image]

Any ideas how to go about stepping into the class library?

Comment: Do you have the code to the class library, or do you only have a reference to the assembly?

Comment: I have added the class library code to my solution file.

Comment: You should have code to stepinto that class library.

Comment: Are you in Release? The other way is as the top answer below - On the IIS WebApp -> Advanced Settings -> Allow Server-Side Debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running from debug, you should see the class library and the symbols loaded in the output window. Look for something that looks like the following:

'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\b2719ea1\480fba3f\assembly\dl3\c439d1ec\8c571aed_7e45cd01\MyClassLibrary.DLL', Symbols loaded.

If you see your class library being loaded but it doesn't say "Symbols loaded" at the end, then it's not finding the .pdb file for some reason.

Also, if you're running from debug, you can attach to WebDev.WebServer40.exe from the 'Attach to Proccess" box. But you shouldn't have to - if the symbols are loaded and you're running in debug mode you ought to be able to hit your breakpoint without explicitly attaching to the process.

Are you able to hit breakpoints in code that's not in your class library?

Comment: "Are you able to hit breakpoints in code that's not in your class library?"... Yes

Comment: from the output window (does not say symbols loaded.. so how I ensure that the pdb is found?):  'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Users\aazzao\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\8770d266\36a71f3e\assembly\dl3\ca9f9930\12082593_6b49cd01\AutoCare.Libraries.Common.DLL'

Comment: That's probably your issue then. Is the class library being rebuild when your rebuild your solution? Does the .dll and the .pdb match up? I'd try deleting the .pdb and doing a clean rebuild and see if it gets regenerated.

Comment: Also - under the solution properties, under Common Properties\Project Dependencies, make sure that your main website depends on your class library.

Comment: Did all the stuff in your last two comments. No luck.

Comment: Have you double-checked the reference? Is it possible that it's not loading the .dll from the bin file, but instead is referencing a different/older version?

Comment: That was it (though I could have sworn it was pointing to the correct path). Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You have to attach to w3wp, the worker process for asp websites, the dll should be in there.

However, if the code is referenced directly, then the built-in VS debugger should work. Are you sure you are running in debug?

Comment: I am running in debug. I don't see w3wp in my process list.

Comment: @DotNetRookie This will not show up until you have run your code once. It needs to be initiated.

Comment: How about aspnet_wp.exe? This is the old version of the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the "Show processes from all users" checked and then attach to the w3wp process for your website.

Comment: I don't see w3wp process in my list of "Attach to Processes" (Show processes from all users is checked)