# Debug pointer not hitting in the class library project

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-debugging, class-library

I have been using a .NET class library in my Asp.NET mvc5 project.  I have set a debug point in the class library but the debugger is not hitting.  I have tried these methods:

1. Load the symbols from module

The module is showing that the symbol is loaded, but the debugger is not hitting and no variable from the debug point is showing on autos.

When I click "Step Over", the debug pointer stands on the line where the library function was called.

[image: Symbol Loaded]

Comment: In an optimized build, there are no(even fewer) guarantees of generated/compiled code matching source code, only that it match source code **behavior** for all inputs. For example, functions are inlined, redundant variables are assimilated into other expressions/omitted entirely, etc. If your debug point aligns with an optimization, that breakpoint may simply not exist to break on in an optimized build. You can try pushing back your breakpoint until it fires, and step from there.

Comment: There are many reasons for this issue, you have to narrow down the scope of the issue. For example, Is the class library set to release mode? That will cause it not to hit break points while debugging. And have you set the the class library to Attach to process ... to the Asp.NET mvc5 project? If the library is external class library, have you disable Just My Code? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8792122/asp-net-class-library-not-hitting-break-points, if above not help, could you please share a sample to me, so I could reproduce this issue.

Comment: the class library was set in debug mode. Here is the code where i called the function from library https://i.imgur.com/An2y82s.png .and here is the code in the library where I set the debug pointer https://i.imgur.com/S4JqxQ3.png